# Shortcut for opening script task editor in BIDS/SSIS?

Tags: ssis, bids

Is there any shortcut for opening script task editor (c# editor) in BIDS/SSIS? This will save me from right clicking the script task, then click on "edit.." and then click on "edit script.."

Comment: you can double click the task rather than right clicking that will get you to the edit script button quicker but unfortunately I don't think there is a way to bypass that screen.